# Java global variables - What is the convention to declare?

Tags: java, variables, coding-style, declaration

I think the question speaks for itself but if it doesnt here is the short explanation for what I meant:

Coding a java programm, what convention should I take to declare a global variable? I Mean, which one below should I use?

```
    public class Variables {

        private variable;
        private Variable;
        private VARIABLE;

        private largerVariable;
        private Larger_Variable;
        private larger_variable;
        private LARGER_VARIABLE;
}
```

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367

Comment: LARGER_VAR is the one which most programmers prefer

Comment: @KamleshArya Not true. This is a name of a **bad** constant. Not a bad variable :)

Comment: These is no so-called Global variable in Java. Java does not have the C/C++ style global variable. The only type of variable you can possibly declare as "global" is "public static final" variables of a class, which can be accessed anywhere. The variable you are defining above are instance variables or member variables. You should use camelCase definition, like carEngine, fileHandler, etc.

Comment: @ZouZou post it as an answer, it has already explained what I wanted. thank you.

Comment: You should try to avoid 'global variables'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several rules:

- Variable names are case-sensitive. A variable's name can be any legal identifier — an unlimited-length sequence of Unicode letters and digits, beginning with a letter, the dollar sign "$", or the underscore character "*". The convention, however, is to always begin your variable names with a letter, not "$" or "*". Additionally, the dollar sign character, by convention, is never used at all. You may find some situations where auto-generated names will contain the dollar sign, but your variable names should always avoid using it. A similar convention exists for the underscore character; while it's technically legal to begin your variable's name with "_", this practice is discouraged. White space is not permitted.
- Subsequent characters may be letters, digits, dollar signs, or underscore characters. Conventions (and common sense) apply to this rule as well. When choosing a name for your variables, use full words instead of cryptic abbreviations. Doing so will make your code easier to read and understand. In many cases it will also make your code self-documenting; fields named cadence, speed, and gear, for example, are much more intuitive than abbreviated versions, such as s, c, and g. Also keep in mind that the name you choose must not be a keyword or reserved word.
- If the name you choose consists of only one word, spell that word in all lowercase letters. If it consists of more than one word, capitalize the first letter of each subsequent word. The names gearRatio and currentGear are prime examples of this convention. If your variable stores a constant value, such as static final int NUM_GEARS = 6, the convention changes slightly, capitalizing every letter and separating subsequent words with the underscore character. By convention, the underscore character is never used elsewhere.

From here
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

If I read these rules right, valid names(by naming convention) will be:

```
private Object largerVariable;
private Object LARGER_VARIABLE;
```

Comment: `LARGER_VARIABLE` should be use for constants.

Comment: ``largerVariable`` for really variables and ``LARGER_VARIABLES`` for constants, that is what I thought, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Another thought is to declare constants such that they can't be changed:

```
private static final boolean POWER_ON = true;
```

Additionally, if I need to define boolean constants, I try to define it so they are affirmative (true) rather than negative (false) so its easier to grasp without thinking about it too much. Example:

I use this:

```
private static final boolean POWER_ON = true;
```

rather than this:

```
private static final boolean POWER_OFF = false;
```

Another consideration:
For boolean variables, I might consider preceeding the word with 'is' or 'has' to indicate its boolean if its not obvious from the word. Example: IS_RADIOACTIVE.

Lastly, I only need to define POWER_ON rather the POWER_OFF since  !POWER_ON means the same thing in a java statement.

Answer (score 1):

Java has no such thing as 'global' variables.
However, if you want to use constants which can be accessed by any other class, most people will declare a `public static final` variable and initialize with the corresponding value right away.

```
public class HttpCodes {
    public static final String NOT_FOUND = "404";
}
```

Can be accessed by any other class: `HttpCodes.NOT_FOUND`

If you're trying to make it an instance variable, go with camelCase `private final String notFound = "404"` for example.

Answer (score 0):

I am assumming global means class level...
as a practice class level variables should be written in capital letters
In most cases they are marked as static so that can be access by all the class methods.
Also, if you believe they would be initialized only once then consider making them final.

correct declaration could be:

```
private static VARIABLE;
private static LARGER_VARIABLE;
```